# Scientific notation removed by labeller with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the labels using label_parsed in facet_grid but it is removing the scientific notation.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, 
    labels = c('atop(atop(a),1.123e-2)','atop(atop(b),1e-3)','atop(atop(c),2.91e-4)'))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ cyl2, labeller=label_parsed)
```

[image: plot]

Although `options("scipen"=-999, "digits"=4)` keeps the scientific notation for this example, it does not work in a more complex plot.

Comment: Can you add an reproducible example where `options("scipen"=-999, "digits"=4)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want this (using character instead of numeric arguments in the plotmath expressions:

```
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, 
    labels = c('atop(atop(a),"1.123e-2")','atop(atop(b),"1e-3")',
                'atop(atop(c),"2.91e-4")'))
```